# angularjs Error: [$injector:strictdi] function($httpProvider) is not using explicit annotation and cannot be invoked in strict mode

Tags: angularjs

```
angular.module('app',[])
.factory('httpRequestInterceptor','APP_VERSION', function (APP_VERSION) {
    var DNAME = sessionStorage.getItem('DNAME');
    var DID = localStorage.getItem('uid');
    return {
      request: function (config) {      
        config.headers['Browser-Agent'] = 'Abc/'+DNAME+'/'+DID+'/'+APP_VERSION+'';
        return config;
      }
    };
})
.config(function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpRequestInterceptor');
});
```

Im gettig the below error.

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
>   Error: [$injector:strictdi] function($httpProvider) is not using explicit annotation and cannot be invoked in strict mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The factory is missing square brackets:

```
angular.module('app',[])
̶.̶f̶a̶c̶t̶o̶r̶y̶(̶'̶h̶t̶t̶p̶R̶e̶q̶u̶e̶s̶t̶I̶n̶t̶e̶r̶c̶e̶p̶t̶o̶r̶'̶,̶ ̶'̶A̶P̶P̶_̶V̶E̶R̶S̶I̶O̶N̶'̶,̶ ̶f̶u̶n̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶(̶A̶P̶P̶_̶V̶E̶R̶S̶I̶O̶N̶)̶ ̶{̶ 
.factory('httpRequestInterceptor',['APP_VERSION', function (APP_VERSION) {
    var DNAME = sessionStorage.getItem('DNAME');
    var DID = localStorage.getItem('uid');
    return {
      request: function (config) {

        config.headers['Browser-Agent'] = 'Abc/'+DNAME+'/'+DID+'/'+APP_VERSION+'';
        return config;
      }
    };
̶}̶)̶
}])
```

And the `.config` is missing explicit annotation:

```
̶.̶c̶o̶n̶f̶i̶g̶(̶f̶u̶n̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶(̶$̶h̶t̶t̶p̶P̶r̶o̶v̶i̶d̶e̶r̶)̶ ̶{̶
.config(["$httpProvider", function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpRequestInterceptor');
̶}̶)̶
}]);
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Dependency Injection - Inline Array Annotation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#inline-array-annotation)
- [AngularJS Error Reference - `$injector:strictdi` Explicit annotation required](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/strictdi)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `APP_VERSION` parameter after `httpRequestInterceptor` and it should work.

```
angular.module('app',[])
.factory('httpRequestInterceptor', function (APP_VERSION) {
```